# Istio: End user Authentication

Tags: authentication, istio

As per the documentation on the website,Istio-Auth provides strong service-to-service and end-user authentication.
I am not able to find more info on end-user authentication. I see all the good stuff about service to service authentication but not the end-user authentication to the services. Is it supported ? Where to find some information on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This end-user auth doc is shared with Istio community. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rU0OgZ0vGNXVlm_WjA-dnfQdS3BsyqmqXnu254pFnZg/edit#heading=h.kt4x5aalmyhf, not sure whether you can view. We are actively working on this feature and will have the basic soon. In the meantime, we will update the website soon.

Answer (score 0):

Note you might need to belong to istio-dev google group to view the doc. The group is public and free to join.